# vim fold: ignore while, if, and for

Tags: vim, folding

In vim, I use syntax folding with C++. How do I ignore the folding in my `while`, `if` and `for` constructs?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/fold-functions-only-not-if-for-switch-td2834720.html, you could do it with

```
:set foldmethod=expr
```

... and then define `foldexpr` to an expression which will say what to fold (see `:help fold-expr`). This would be very tedious, though, and there must be a better way.

Comment: I working in foldexpr https://github.com/juanpabloaj/absolutFold, but I searching a more simple solution

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a perfect answer you could try to fiddle around with foldlevel too see if that might fit your needs.

```
:help fold-foldlevel
```

It will not solve your problem perfectly but seeing as C++ normally don't go that deep I am thinking that you could set it to your standard function level and have it all folded up to that level.

Hope it helps :)